# .NET 6 Core Web API with Elastic Search

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to use the elastic search in my project that made it with the ASP.NET Core 6 web-API?

It is possible to use it with asp core web API and How?

Comment: Yes it is, there are libraries allowing to use Elastic Search from .NET.

Comment: What happened when you searched Elasticsearch documentation for "C# client"?

Comment: It looks like a how-to question. You may search it on a search engine ie. google.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Elasticsearch.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elasticsearch.net/#dependencies-tab) and [Nest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST) in .NET 6 Web API.

sample code:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://example.com:9200"))
.DefaultIndex("people");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

you can define a model for messages...

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then send the message to Elastic:

```
var person = new Person
{
   Id = 1,
   FirstName = "Martijn",
   LastName = "Laarman"
};

var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(person);
```

See this link for more information: [Elasticsearch in .NET](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/nest-getting-started.html)